# Location of STS directory on Eclipse plugin install

Tags: grails, groovy, eclipse-plugin, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I've installed the STS tools in eclipse to use with grails:
http://grails.org/STS+Integration

I've encountered the following problem when trying to install the "Groovy Eclipse" extension under the Language and Framework Tooling:

```
cannot install groovy-eclipse because sts installation directory is read-only
```

So I'm assuming I need to make the directory writable!

Problem is, I cannot figure out where this directory acually got installed to!

Does anyone have an idea?

Thanks

Comment: which os?  plugins dir in your STS folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to chmod or chown the dir that you installed STS into.  On my box I have install STS under /opt/springsource